# How to access image from ethernet camera

Tags: web-access

I have a Edimax IC-3140W ethernet security camera. It acts as a web host where the video feed can be viewed in a browser. Navigating to its ip address http://ip.ip.ip.ip, it will ask for a password and username and then redirects to http://ip.ip.ip.ip/live.asp?r=nnnnnnnnn.nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn which is a web page where the video is in a frame. Right clicking on the video and selecting copy image will copy a frame to the clipboard. Right clicking and selecting "Copy image address" copies the link http://ip.ip.ip.ip/snapshot.cgi. If I view that link in a browser I get the video on a page by itself.

I want to capture a frame of that video in Mathematica. I have a different camera where I use

```
Import[URLRead["http://ip2.ip2.ip2.ip2:8080/?action=snapshot"]]
```

but that doesn't seem to work with this camera.

I also tried

```
Dynamic@URLExecute["http://10.2.1.15/snapshot.cgi", {"Username" -> "admin","Password" -> "notmypa$$word"}]
```

but that returns

```
   --myboundary
   X-CurrentUsers: Too many users
   Content-Length: 0
   Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: This worked
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87848/how-to-connect-to-a-video-stream